# Hourly wise sales report

Tags: mysql

I have the data Like

```
Sales   Order_date
27  2022-03-29 7:27:12
22  2022-03-29 7:27:22
20  2022-03-29 7:27:28
15  2022-03-29 7:27:59
29  2022-03-29 7:33:31
18  2022-03-29 7:46:17
10  2022-03-29 7:48:40
21  2022-03-29 8:09:25
24  2022-03-29 8:15:58
18  2022-03-29 8:16:36     etc...
```

Can I get the o/p like below mentioned  hourly based total_sales.

```
Ordr_date   Time     Total_Sales
2022-03-29  7:00 AM       141
2022-03-29  8:00 AM       63
```

Thanking you.

Comment: extract the date from the orer date, extract the hour from the order date, group by the date and the hour, count the sales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select date(order_date) as date,
       hour(order_date) as hour ,
       sum(sales) as total_sales
from test_tbl
group by date,hour;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75443040d8cb366c7c0ed464a7cf97ee)

MySQL function:

[Time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time)

[Hour](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour)

Comment: demo tool is really cool.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try:
Mysql Query

```
select date(order_date) as date,DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%I:%i %p') as Time ,sum(sales) as total_sales
from test_tbl
group by date,hour;
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go, I have taken the table name as Sales_Table so change it according to your needs,

```
select table1.`Time`
  ,max(table1.date_order) 
  ,sum(table1.sales) 
from (select *
         ,date(order_date) as date_order
         ,CONCAT(hour(order_date),':00') as `Time` 
  from Sales_Table
as table1 
group by table1.`Time`;
```

Comment: use close ")" after the Sales_Table. query is working..